# Вывод дня недели по заданной дате

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, datetime

Нужен Ваш совет.

Есть список, в котором указано расписание работы ресторанов, напр:

```
"Tres","Mon-Thu, Sun 11:30 am - 10 pm  / Fri-Sat 11:30 am - 11 pm"
"Bai Thong Thai Cuisine","Mon-Sat 11 am - 11 pm  / Sun 11 am - 10 pm"
"Sapporo-Ya Japanese Restaurant","Mon-Sat 11 am - 11 pm  / Sun 11 am - 10:30 pm"
```

Пишу программу, которая по вводу даты (напр. 02.02.2019 14:30) - выведёт все рестораны, которые работают в этот период.

Не работал раньше c модулем `Datetime`.

Поделитесь мыслями, как можно это организовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import datetime
import calendar

print(calendar.day_abbr[datetime.date(2019, 2, 2).weekday()])
#Sat
```

**Update** (для формата "ДД.ММ.ГГГГ"):

```
import datetime
import calendar

mydate = "21.01.2019"

workdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(mydate, "%d.%m.%Y")
print(calendar.day_abbr[workdate.date().weekday()])
#Mon
```

Comment: Вы гений!__________Спасибо!!!!!!!!__________Можно ли в данном случае использовать другой формат, т.е. не «YEAR.MONTH.DAY», а «DAY.MONTH.YEAR»??

Comment: @AlexandrS я обновил ответ. Почитайте про метод `strptime` и его форматы для конвертации строковой переменной в объект `datetime`.

Comment: БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО!!!!!!!!